# Do a bar magnet's and Earth's north magnetic poles have the same polarity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, geomagnetism, ferromagnetism

Are the north magnetic pole of the earth and the north pole of a bar magnet of the same polarity? Please Explain. I don't seem to understand the question.

Comment: could you please explain why? @UKH

Comment: @UKH - "polarity" has nothing to do with strength, and everything to do with the direction of the magnetic field lines.

Comment: @Floris yeah, my bad. I misunderstood the question. I thought OP is having doubt with pole strength. Just got confused with polarity and pole strength. I raised a question about that in the comment.

Comment: @UKH no need to apologize- your comments were confusing because you were confused. Happens to all of us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The earth's North Pole is a "magnetic south pole". With a compass, the part of the needle that points north is a magnetic north pole. With magnets, opposite poles attract, so what we call North on the earth must be  magnetic south to attract the needle's north.